# how to fix messy Excel import with datetime.datetime and datetime.time objects in the same column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I have to read multiple Excel-files into a pandas data frame using `pd.read_excel()`. The Excel files have a column with a date and a column with a time (HH:MM:SS). In the pandas df, the time-column gets interpreted as `datetime.time`, but whenever the time is midnight `00:00:00`, it gets interpreted as `1899-12-30T00:00:00.000Z` which is a `datetime.datetime`.

```
|  Excel   |         pandas df        | type in pandas df |
|----------|--------------------------|-------------------|
| 23:30:00 | 23:30:00                 | datetime.time     |
| 23:45:00 | 23:45:00                 | datetime.time     |
| 00:00:00 | 1899-12-30T00:00:00.000Z | datetime.datetime |
| 00:15:00 | 00:15:00                 | datetime.time     |
```

How can I force pandas read the entire time-column as time or datetime (I don't care which, I just want them all to be the same)?

What I need in the end is a datetime-column (can't be the index, so no "parse dates") where I simply combine the Date- and Time-columns. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how, because of the messy combination of time and datetime in the Time-column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the column to string, parse to pandas datetime with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), and optionally format to HH:MM:SS string again with strftime. Example, assuming 'time' being the column in question,

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str)).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Would e.g. give you

```
df
       time
0  23:30:00
1  23:45:00
2  00:00:00
3  00:15:00
```

You could also specify to import the column directly as string with a keyword in the call to [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), e.g. `dtype={'time': str}`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first line of code worked. Importing directly as string however doesn't work for me (has no effect).

Comment: Glad I could help! Importing as string would still require the step of conversion to datetime. Alternatively, you could also set a converter as keyword, `converters={'time': lambda t: pd.to_datetime(str(t))}` but that's doing the same thing while being less readable imho ;-)